# How to filtering of data in List & Label reports from user?

Tags: c#, sql-server, report, filtering, listlabel

We use an MS SQL database directly as a data source for List & Label. All tables, columns and data records are then always available at once.

However, a created report should not always display all data, so we have selected the appearance condition within the report in such a way that only certain data of a table is displayed.

But we don't want to create and offer a separate report for each possible condition in a table, where each one has its own appearance condition. Also the user should not be able to change the report itself in the designer. Is there a simple and user-friendly way that the user can decide from "outside" for the report which data should be displayed?

Comment: Not entirely clear if you want to filter the columns (i.e. decide dynamically, which fields to display) or the rows (i.e. change the records that are shown). Can you clarify?

Comment: An SQL query (Command_Text) is a string.  So you where (filters) and added pieces of the WHERE string.  A just combine WHERE filters with "AND".  I used string.Join(" AND ", array);

Comment: @JBartlau I mean the data rows should be filtered in the report from user.

Comment: @jdweng We are using the SqlConnectionDataprovider of List & Label which just gets the connection string - no queries. And I'm looking for an in-build solution.

Comment: A query is any database transaction.  You are using Entity and can use RawSQL which you can send a string query to the database.  See https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/raw-sql.  So you can create your custom where string like I said in response above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to achieve this is using a [report parameter](https://docu.combit.net/designer/en/#!Documents/reportparameters.htm). You can configure them from Project > Report Parameters:

[image: Report Parameter Configuration]

As you can see from the screenshot, the data for the report parameter can come from the database, but you can also offer a choice from a predefined list of entries or even allow the user to freely type a text. There are date pickers for date values etc.

These parameters are shown above the preview in desktop apps. In web apps, you have a separate pane - see the "Chart With Report Parameters" sample [here](https://www.combit.com/web-reporting-list-label/).

Once you have configured the parameter as required, use it in the "Data Filter" property of your report container items. Note that you should look for a filter that translates to your database's syntax. [This blog article](https://www.combit.blog/en/filtering-at-database-level/) has more details on the concept.